# Admin access on Pi 3

Tags: filesystem

I have tried to edit files on my pi 3, such as pyaudio.py but cannot because system keeps telling me permission denied, why is this? How can I get admin acces even though it is my system? Anyone one please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of commands need root privileges to be executed properly. You can grant them command-wise starting your commands with `sudo` or you can change the permission settings file-wise e.g. allowing all users to read, write and execute a file by using the command `sudo chmod 777 /path/to/your/file`.

However, giving all permissions to everyone circumvents the built-in permission system which is a security safeguard. You should always think about which user really needs what permissions and only grant those. For more information on what chmod does and what those numbers mean, read [this post](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `pyaudio.py` does, or where it is located. I assume in one of the system directories, in which case modifying it is not a good idea.

The normal way to modify system files is `sudo nano /path/pyaudio.py` (or other editor of your choice), but first you should explore if a local copy or other `.config` option is available. If you do choose to modify it make a copy first.

It is a **BAD** idea to modify permissions of system files.